# Why does this code not duplicate the body of the page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Ok, I hate implementing things that I don't quite understand, and I am losing sleep over this one.

Here is the situation:  I am working on an ASP.NET website that started development by someone else a while ago and they were at the time using VB.NET.  I was asked to move the VIEWSTATE of my webpages to the bottom of the page because that is supposed to enhance searchability of our pages by web spiders.

So, after a few hours of searches here and there, I pieced this class together and it is working very well so far.  But it bothers the heck out of me that I don't understand why it works well, please help me understand why it works.  Here is the class code:

```
Public Class Page
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

        Dim viewStateStart As Integer
        Dim viewStateEnd As Integer
        Dim viewState As String = ""
        Dim FormEnd As Integer

        Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        ' WHY does this work?  Why is this call to the base method not causing
        ' the HTML body to be duplicated????        
        MyBase.Render(hw)

        Dim bodyHTML As String = sw.ToString()

        hw.Close()
        sw.Close()

        viewStateStart = bodyHTML.IndexOf("<input type=""hidden"" name=""__VIEWSTATE""")

        If viewStateStart > -1 Then
            viewStateEnd = bodyHTML.IndexOf("/>", viewStateStart) + 2
            viewState = bodyHTML.Substring(viewStateStart, viewStateEnd - viewStateStart)
            bodyHTML = bodyHTML.Remove(viewStateStart, viewStateEnd - viewStateStart)

            FormEnd = bodyHTML.IndexOf("</form>") - 1
            bodyHTML = bodyHTML.Insert(FormEnd, viewState)
        End If

        writer.Write(bodyHTML)
    End Sub

End Class
```

My problem is that I do not understand for the life of me, how come this class calls the base method RENDER, and gets away with not rendering the body of the asp page twice, since the base method would have called also Writer.Write(htmlWriter)

Why is that not the case?

Thanks for any help and comments folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice where the base class is writing its html:

```
Dim sw As StringWriter = New StringWriter()
Dim hw As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

MyBase.Render(hw)
```

`hw` is not the writer that was passed as a parameter, it is just a temporary html writer. This is not what is going to the actual output.

Later on the method uses whatever base method has written:

```
Dim bodyHTML As String = sw.ToString()
```

And plays around with it, moving ViewState field to the end of the body string. And only at the very end of the method html is written to the actual writer, that will output the end html:

```
writer.Write(bodyHTML)
```

Comment: I think I can sleep now :)   Thank you very much Andrei.  When I reach reputation 15 I will be able to upvote :)

Comment: @AjaxNgnurse, for what it worth, you can mark answer as accepted. Mainly to indicate that it helped you, in case someone else has a similar question and finds this thread